# Does anyone know why I am getting an error when I try to use pip? I just downloaded that latest version of python and it is not working

Tags: python, pip, pycharm

When I try to see the version of pip that I have to check that it is downloaded, this is what comes up

```
    C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip --version
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Please I need all the help I can get. All of the forums or websites I have found were extremely out of date.

Comment: Is Python in your PATH?

Comment: Wherever you've installed `pip`, it's not in your `PATH`.

Comment: How can I add pip to my PATH, or how can I see if it is there

Comment: What is your OS and what Python distribution and version do you have?

Comment: Do you mean like windows 10, because that is what I am on

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+is+not+recognized+as+an+internal+or+external+command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People are telling you to add pip to your PATH, which is correct, but if you don't know what that means, let me tell you (assuming you're using Windows).

1. Go to the folder where Python is installed. For me it's:

C:\Users\daniel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32

2. In this folder, there's a Scripts folder. Go into this folder and then copy the file path. In the file explorer, click in the bar at the top that tells you what folder you're in. It will turn into the highlighted path. Copy this path.
3. Click the Windows icon in the taskbar and type env, then click the option that says "Edit the System Environment Variables"
4. Near the bottom of the pop up, click Environment Variables.
5. In the top half, called User Variables, find the one from the list called Path. Click it and then click Edit.
6. Click New from the right side and then paste in the file path from before, the Scripts path.
7. Click OK at each window to save this change.
8. Close the terminal window and open a new one.

You're all set to use pip.

Comment: This worked like a charm. No other tutorial I found was as clear as this one. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Just as a heads up, you can use this for any other commands you want to run from the command line. So if you downloaded an Android app that wants you to plug your Android phone into a computer and run an adb command, you'd install adb, then add the adb folder to your path. An alternative, if you don't want to add things to the path, is to open a command prompt in the folder itself itself.

Answer (score 0):

Python is not pip

Follow instructions [here](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/install-pip-windows/) to download pip after downloading python

After which add to path. By default pip is installed into "C:\Python34\Scripts\pip"

```
setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Python34\Scripts"
```

The location your pip is installed to will differ depending on your OS and setup

Comment: This is not universally true. E.g. it won't work for Anaconda, it doesn't create a C:/Python34 folder.

Comment: Also, many Python distributions automatically include pip so no need for separate installation.

Comment: @FatihAkici Great point. I wasn't thinking anaconda.